# Why do multiple parallel invocations of NetworkManager.addToQueueAndWait interfere with each other?

Tags: android, codenameone

Multiple invocations to the jsonRequest() method from different Threads (Timer-1 and EDT) do interfere with each other and even one call returns the result of a previous invocation

My CodeNameOne application uses a background Thread (Timer-1) to retrieve and display data from a REST service every second and it allows the user to issue commands that also issue REST calls from the EDT thread.

```
private Map<String, Object> jsonRequest(String url, String body, String cmd, int timeoutMs) {
    long startTs = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try {
        request = new ConnectionRequest();
        request.setReadResponseForErrors(true);
        // request.setTimeout(timeoutMs);
        // Shai: Timeout in Codename One is currently limited to connection timeout and 
        // doesn't apply to read timeout so once a connection is made it will last
        request.setHttpMethod(cmd); 
        request.setPost(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("POST") || cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("PUT") || cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("PATCH"));
        if (body != null) {
            request.addRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setContentType("application/json");
            request.setRequestBody(body);
            request.setWriteRequest(true);
        }
        request.setUrl(url);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(request);
        long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTs;
        Log.p(cmd + ": " + url + " " + duration + " ms");

        if (request.getResponseCode() >= 400 || request.getResponseData() == null) {
            Log.p("responseCode=" + request.getResponseCode() + " responseData=" + request.getResponseData());
            return null;
        }
        Log.p(cmd + ": " + url + " " + new String(request.getResponseData()));
        Map<String, Object> result = new JSONParser().parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(request.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        problemHandler.handle(cmd, url, e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Actually result of multiple invocations get mixed up.
I would expect that each call to addToQueueAndWait() waits for the right result and returns just when the result is there.
I observed this problem to happen much more often on Android than on iOS or the simulator

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that's what you are seeing. I see that request is defined in the class level as a variable so I'm guessing you are seeing a typical race condition where the request variable gets replaced while one is sent and by the time you reach the parsing it's a different object.

There is no need to use a thread for polling as networking already runs on a separate thread (or more this is usually determined in the `init(Object)` method).

I would suggest using a timer for a single invocation that's invoked after the response finishes.

A better approach would be websockets though: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/introducing-codename-one-websocket-support.html

With websockets the server can push out an update notification. This will save you the need to constantly poll the server. It saves on device battery life and resources on server/device.